# Rails w/ Turbolinks window.onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I currently have a Rails application that uses Turbolinks. In this app, I am trying to track the amount of time spent on a specific view. I have looked at countless questions and gone through multiple variations of called window.onbeforeunload, window.beforeunload, window.on('beforeunload')... My current attempt is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var start = Date.now();

var id = gon.subjId;
var rand_index = gon.randIndex;
var index = gon.index;

console.log('showing article ' + index + ' at index ' + rand_index + ' for ' + id);

$(document).on('turbolinks:before-change', function() {
  $.post('/log', {subj_id: id, article: {index: index, rand_index: rand_index, time_spent: Date.now()-start}},
    function(response) {
    });
})
```

});

I know that the function using the AJAX request works; however, it is not called. How can I get this function to call when the back button is pressed?

Comment: I think Rails 5 has changed the namespace of turbolinks' events to `turbolinks` instead of `page` try using `turbolinks:before-change`

Comment: I tried that and updated the question, however it still didn't work

Comment: `turbolinks:load`now has a `event.data.timing`, isn't it the date that you are expecting to see? Refer to this [link](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the underlying error was but I changed the script to this and works like a charm:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var start = Date.now();

var id = gon.subjId;
var rand_index = gon.randIndex;
var index = gon.index;

console.log('showing article ' + index + ' at index ' + rand_index + ' for ' + id);

function logVisit() {
  console.log('logging visit');

  $.post('/log', {subj_id: id, article: {index: index, rand_index: rand_index, time_spent: Date.now()-start}},
    function(response) {
  });
  document.removeEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', logVisit);
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:before-cache', logVisit);
});
```